# How to access columns after creating multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am making my `DataFrame` like this:

```
influenza_data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['year', 'week', 'weekly_infections'])
```

and then I create `MultiIndex` from `year` and `week` columns:

```
influenza_data = influenza_data.set_index(['year', 'week'])
```

If I have `MultiIndex` my `DataFrame` looks like this:

```
          weekly_infections
year week                  
2009 40                6600
     41                7100
     42                7700
     43                8300
     44                8600
...                     ...
2019 10                8900
     11                6200
     12                5500
     13                3900
     14                3300
```

and `data_influenza.columns`:

```
Index(['weekly_infections'], dtype='object')
```

The problem I have is that I can't access `year` and `week` columns now.

If I try `data_influenza['week']` or `year` I get `KeyError: 'week'`. I can only do `data_influenza.weekly_infections` and that returns a whole `DataFrame`

I know if I remove `multiIndex` I can easily access them but why can't I `data_influenza.year` or `week` with `MultiIndex`? I specified `columns` when I was creating `Dataframe`

Comment: you can access the multiindex with ``df.loc[2009,:]`` or ``df.query("year==2009")``  or ``df.query("year==2009 and week==40")`` ... there are a number of options. You can have a look [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#multiindex-query-syntax) and [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)

Comment: @sammywemmy what would be equivalent of `df['year']` to get whole `year` column?

Comment: not sure I understand. The `year` is already an index, so you should have all the years.

Comment: `year` was not an index, that's the thing that was confusing me. I posted my  `data_influenza.columns` and it only shows `Index(['weekly_infections'], dtype='object')` so the only index I could work with was `weakly_infections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Pandas documentation says [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html), you can access `MultiIndex` object levels by `get_level_values(index)` method:

```
influenza_data.index.get_level_values(0)    # year
influenza_data.index.get_level_values(1)    # week
```

Obviously, the `index` parameter represents the order of indices.